# how to remove empty tag from output xml using for-each loop in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

input xml:

```
<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>

     461

   </sb:first-page>

   <sb:last-page>

     70

   </sb:last-page>

</sb:pages> 

<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>

     461

  </sb:first-page>

</sb:pages>
```

my output xml:

```
<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>461</sb:first-page>

   <sb:last-page>70</sb:last-page>

</sb:pages> 

<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>461</sb:first-page>

   <sb:last-page/>

</sb:pages>
```

i dont want second last-page in my output xml. because sb:pages[last()]/sb:last-page is not in my input xml.
i am using for-each loop in my xslt. what i have to do to get the output xml without empty tag?

My expected output xml is:

```
<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>461</sb:first-page>

   <sb:last-page>70</sb:last-page>

</sb:pages> 

<sb:pages>

   <sb:first-page>461</sb:first-page>

</sb:pages>
```

anyone help me to solve this problem?

my xslt is:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="/pages/sb:pages"/>

     <sb:first-page><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(sb:first-page)"/> 

      </sb:first-page>

     <sb:last-page><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(sb:last-page)"/>

      </sb:last-page>

 </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a matter of removing empty elements but rather it's about not adding them in the first place. The solution is to use a "push" approach instead of a "pull" approach.

Replace this:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/pages/sb:pages"/>

     <sb:first-page><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(sb:first-page)"/> 

      </sb:first-page>

     <sb:last-page><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(sb:last-page)"/>

      </sb:last-page>

 </xsl:for-each>
```

With this:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="/pages/sb:pages" />
```

and add these templates:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
</xsl:template>
```

This is a generic approach that will normalize the space in all text nodes that are not matched by some other template.

Comment: A very good illustration of why rule-based processing is better at dealing with semi-structured data than rigid procedural processing.

Comment: Where i have to add the apply templates and template match in my xsl code

Comment: @Anitha As I said, replace all of the code in your post with that `apply-templates` line. There's only one place where you can put `templates` in an XSLT, which is directly inside the `xsl:stylesheet` root element. It doesn't matter what order you add them in.